# Error: Wrong type argument: symbolp, (t)

Tags: arguments

I'm new to emacs and try to learn elisp. I've read some tutorials and try to build now my own customized emacs. Looking at this [blog](http://y.tsutsumi.io/emacs-from-scratch-part-2-package-management.html) I want to write a similar script for automatically installing required packages.

In the blog the author defines a variable `required-package` which binds to a list of required packages. Then he writes (I quote):

```
; my-packages.el
(require 'cl)

; method to check if all packages are installed
(defun packages-installed-p ()
  (loop for p in required-packages
        when (not (package-installed-p p)) do (return nil)
        finally (return t)))
```

My goal is to write a similar function which does not depend on the common lisp package (since I would like to learn elisp :)). So I tried:

```
(defun check-required-packages (list-check)
  "The function check if the packages in LIST-CHECK are installed"
  (let ((return '(t))) ; return list
    (dolist (p list-check return) ; for each p in package execute the body and finally return RERTURN.
      (when (not (package-installed-p p))
    (add-to-list return nil)))
    return))
```

Having also a variable `required-packages` binding to such a list leads to the error:

```
(check-required-packages required-packages)
Wrong type argument: symbolp, (t)
```

I dont understand this. Since I can define

```
(setq a '(t))
```

without a problem.

Comment: Don't use add-to-list for local variables.  It'll break if you enable lexical binding. Use push or cl-pushnew instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is `(add-to-list return nil)`. The first argument of `add-to-list` must be the symbol of the variable holding the list and not the list itself.
That means you have to write `(add-to-list 'return nil)` instead.

You can find such errors easily yourself if you use `edebug`.
I think you have `lisp-interaction-mode` or `emacs-lisp-mode` as major mode of the buffer where you try your code. You find `edebug` in both modes in the major mode menu, either `Lisp-Interaction` or `Emacs-Lisp` as menu item `Instrument Function For Debugging`. Place point on the closing parenthesis of the `defun` you want to instrument for debugging and click on that menu item.
Afterwards call the instrumented function. Emacs will enter the debugger on your function.
The buffer will be read-only and the key-bindings are redefined. If you press space you can execute the function form after form and see the effects.

Another way to debug your code is to check the option `Options -> Enter Debugger On Error`. Then run your code. Emacs will show you the backtrace when the error occurs. That gives you a quite good feeling for the place where the error is.

Comment: Many thx for the debugging part. I'm really sorry if this was a too basic questions. As I pointed out, just starting with it. Really appreciated your help

Answer (score 2):

As documented in the Info for Elisp:

> The argument SYMBOL is not implicitly quoted; `add-to-list` is an
>     ordinary function, like `set` and unlike `setq`.  Quote the
>     argument yourself if that is what you want.
>
> Here's a scenario showing how to use `add-to-list`:
>
> ```
> (setq foo '(a b))
>       => (a b)
>
> (add-to-list 'foo 'c)     ;; Add `c'.
>       => (c a b)
> ```